# For switch statements, does it matter if I have a default if all the case statements return?

Tags: coding-style, switch-statement, maintainability

which one is better for the long run, or does it not matter?

```
switch ($something) { 
  case 1: 
    return 2;
  case 2: 
    return 3;
  case 3: 
    return 4;
  default:
    // throw exception     
}
```

vs

```
switch ($something) { 
  case 1: 
    return 2;
  case 2: 
    return 3;
  case 3: 
    return 4;    
}
// throw exception
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is generally good practice to handle unexpected cases in the `default`. e.g.:

```
switch ($something) { 
    case 1: 
        return 2;
    case 2: 
        return 3;
    case 3: 
        return 4;   
    default:
        // throw exception
}
```

This is common practice, so generally for other people (and yourself) reading the code in the future, the intention will be clearer. It also makes it clearer that the exception is related to the switch statement.